# cloud foundry is providing same instance of my web page to every device

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web, cloud-foundry

Lets say there is some static variables in a class and when user on device 1 store some data on it and at the same time some other user on device 2 open the web page then he/she also gets the same data store in that variable,,insted of the deafult data i store .
I think cloud Foundry provide different isolated environment to every user that goes on the website but in that case that is not happening.
Please do tell if this the same behavior what cloud foundry really provide or i am missing something .

Answer (score 2):

> cloud Foundry provide different isolated environment to every user that goes on the website

That statement is absolutely ***not*** true. Each instance of an application does get an isolated execution environment, but CF creates exactly as many application instances as you tell it to (e.g. via the `-i` parameter on `cf push` or `cf scale`). The platform does not scale up instances per user. No platform I know of does that, as it would be incredibly inefficient.

If your web application needs to keep unique data for each user of the app, it will need to implement session management logic inside the app. You can't do this with static fields in classes. Exactly how you implement session management is dependent on the language and frameworks you are using.